# Pre-load pages in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

TL;DR - I want to be able to pre-load pages before user routes to them, how can this be achieved?

I have a site that uses react-query to fetch and store data. So when the user enter the page on root navigation I show a list of products. These are stored in the cache. If a user presses the product the user is routed to the view for that product. But since I already fetched the product when I showed it in the list the data is fetched from cache but the layout is fetched from the server. What I want to achieve is when root is loaded, I fetch the product view in the background and if the user presses the product the view will open much faster since both layout and product already are fetched.

br

Answer (score 0):

NextJS has a cache feature for the components (server-side). Also, instead of saving data of your products in cache, you can use [ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration) for product pages (if you have > 1000 product pages).

If you have less than 1000 product pages, you should use [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#using-getstaticprops-to-fetch-data-from-a-cms) (better for SEO, all pages are cached during build time)

If you have dynamic data on the product pages (for example: the stock of the product shown on the page may differ), you should use ISR.

I recommend you ISR because:

1. It's similar to `getStaticProps`
2. ISR pages are "cached", so pages are really fast
3. You can choose which pages should be build during build time (to reduce build costs) and refresh delay.
4. Good for SEO

Even if you write pre-load views and cache it, you will decrease speed of your "root" page because of overcharging your DB with requests.

P.S. In my projects I am using ISR for product pages.

Comment: I've run ISR before. But its not what I want to achieve. I fetch data which I want to store in the cache. ISR only stores sites while visited.

Comment: So, you don't have native logic; anyway you can't really "prefetch" something

Comment: gatsby have this feetcher where they preloads the page when u hover on a link to internal page. I want to achive the same here

Comment: Hi @JediSchmedi, I'm looking for the same feature of Gatsby. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @AlexMelw this can now be solved using next/link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link
Hover the link and the data for the page is fetched. 

I run nextjs together with react-query then I can store and work with the data as I please. :)